# How to auto scroll a div element full of images continuously infinitely?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations, autoscroll

I am trying to make a web page which has three div with 7 images each. Those images in their divs are placed side by side.

I am trying to implement an auto scrolling for those 3 divs. When first div scrolls say x% to the top and is not visible then that x% should come at the bottom.

I tried various resources and ways but none of them are stating things clearly. Currently this is my html file:

```
<div class="images">

    <div id="row1" class="row">
        <div id="im1" class="column">
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im2" class="column">
            <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im3" class="column">
            <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im4" class="column">
            <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im5" class="column">
            <img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im6" class="column">
            <img src="img/img6.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im7" class="column">
            <img src="img/img7.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="row2" class="row">
        <div id="im8" class="column">
            <img src="img/img8.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im9" class="column">
            <img src="img/img9.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im10" class="column">
            <img src="img/img10.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im11" class="column">
            <img src="img/img11.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im12" class="column">
            <img src="img/img12.png" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im13" class="column">
            <img src="img/img13.jpeg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im14" class="column">
            <img src="img/img14.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="row3" class="row">
        <div id="im15" class="column">
            <img src="img/img15.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im16" class="column">
            <img src="img/img16.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im17" class="column">
            <img src="img/img17.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im18" class="column">
            <img src="img/img18.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im19" class="column">
            <img src="img/img19.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im20" class="column">
            <img src="img/img20.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>

        <div id="im21" class="column">
            <img src="img/img21.jpg" alt="movie">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And this is my CSS file:

```
html, body {
    background-color: #222222;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
    float: left;
}

.column img {
    width:  200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.images {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.row {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.column img {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 10s linear infinite;
    animation: bannermove 10s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes bannermove {
    from {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(-200%);
    }
}
```

This make those divs scroll but as I said, the part that has been scrolled to the top and is not visible is not coming back to the bottom.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" }, 1000);
```

You can using JQuery to do it.replace "300px" to height your want.set timeout for timer to auto-scroll

Comment: I didn't understand. How will timeout set the x% scrolled part to the bottom? Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: I edited. animate with timeout is how the speed is. set-timeout() is no correct.